# SQL issue with NULL values on SUM

Tags: sql

I'm currently working on some sql stuff, but running in a bit of an issue.

I've got this method that looks for cash transactions, and takes off the cashback but sometimes there are no cash transactions, so that value turns into NULL and you can't subtract from NULL.
I've tried to put an ISNULL around it, but it still turns into null.

Can anyone help me with this?

```
;WITH tran_payment AS
(
SELECT 1 AS payment_method, NULL AS payment_amount, null as tran_header_cid
UNION ALL
SELECT 998 AS payment_method, 2 AS payment_amount, NULL as tran_header_cid
), 
paytype AS
(
SELECT 1 AS mopid, 2 AS mopshort
),
tran_header AS
(
SELECT 1 AS cid
)
            SELECT p.mopid                     AS mopid,
                   p.mopshort                  AS descript,
                   payment_value AS PaymentValue,  
                   ISNULL(DeclaredValue, 0.00) AS DeclaredValue
            from   paytype p
                   LEFT OUTER JOIN (SELECT CASE 
                       When (tp.payment_method = 1) 
                       THEN
                     (ISNULL(SUM(tp.payment_amount), 0)
                     - (SELECT ISNULL(SUM(ABS(tp.payment_amount)), 0)
                           FROM tran_payment tp
                           INNER JOIN tran_header th on tp.tran_header_cid = th.cid
        WHERE payment_method = 998
        ) )
     ELSE SUM(tp.payment_amount)
     END as payment_value,
     tp.payment_method,
     0   as DeclaredValue
     FROM   tran_header th
     LEFT OUTER JOIN tran_payment tp
     ON tp.tran_header_cid = th.cid
     GROUP  BY payment_method) pmts
     ON p.mopid = pmts.payment_method
```

Comment: What DBMS are you using?

Comment: Are you perhaps missing an ISNULL() in your ELSE clause?

Comment: @Daniel from ISNULL, I guess it is MS SQL

Comment: Please give your whole query. It just seems to start out of nowhere with `paytype p` at the moment.

Comment: Updated it with the whole select statement.

Comment: @Lex - I've taken the liberty of editing it. Can you populate the CTEs with example data that demonstrate the issue? (Add additional rows to them with `UNION ALL`)

Comment: @Martin, I've updated the CTEs. As you can see the issue is that the peyment_method of 1 does not always have a value.

Comment: Looking at it, I think the issue might be that we will never enter the case statement, because there are no transactions with a payment_method of 1

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Maybe `COALESCE()` can help you?

You can try this:

```
SUM(COALESCE(tp.payment_amount, 0))
```

or

```
COALESCE(SUM(tp.payment_amount), 0)
```

`COALESCE(arg1, arg2, ..., argN)` returns the first non-null argument from the list.

Answer (score 2):

try to put ISNULL inside SUM and ABS, i.e. around the actual field, like this

```
SUM(ISNULL(tp.payment_amount, 0))

SUM(ABS(ISNULL(tp.payment_amount, 0)))
```

Comment: Shouldn't make any difference `NULL` values are ignored in calculating the `SUM`. The only time that `SUM(x)` will return `NULL` will be if all the inputs are `NULL` then just wrapping the aggregate in `ISNULL` will have the same effect.

Answer (score 1):

I don't have MS SQL to test here, but would it work to put the `ISNULL` around the `SELECT`? Maybe, `ISNULL` isn't triggered at all, if there are no matching rows...